# Trying to Install MAT tool in Eclipse ADT

Tags: eclipse, heap-memory

I am trying to install MAT tool in Android Eclipse from the Help-> Install New Software.

This is the [link](http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.5/update-site/) I am using.

It is the correct link and a new one. But it is not getting installed and the installation wizard is crashing. Here I am posting the picture of the error. Please help me resolve this error.

[image: Error picture]

Comment: You might be behind a proxy that does not allow JARs to be downloaded. Frequently you will receive an HTML file explaining why from the proxy instead. Can you check it?

Comment: I have not received any HTML file....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to install the MAT tool for android eclipse. There were two tools which were showed while installing the software though Help->Install New Software.
Here I am attaching the image which shows the three options 
1. Memory Analyzer for Eclipse IDE
   1.1 Memory Analyzer
   1.2 Memory Analyzer Charts (Optional)
2. Stand Alone Memory Analyzer
[image: image for explanation]

Just check the Memory Analyzer(1.1). Do not check the Memory Analyzer  Charts which is optional(1.2)

We need not install the Stand Alone(1.2).

I am not sure why it is showing error if I check both. Ideally it must not show error. I have een turned off my windows firewall while installing the softwares.